# How do I get my question privileges back?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, moderation

I have reached my question limit is there a way to get it lifted?

It has now been 1.5 years since I've been banned to 1 question every 6 months. There is something wrong with the system parameters. Nothing in the answers are helping even with the up votes lately received. Thanks. My last option is to abandon this account and start a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your original question rather than the many duplicate questions you've made on the meta [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/question-ban-still-in-effect), [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/appealling-for-question-ban-to-be-lifted), and [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/i-want-to-ask-questions-a-better-reputation-scoring-is-needed)

The best way to get out of a ban is to improve your posts as explained [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  The question ban system is logical: if you ask too many low-quality questions, it'll stop you until you clean up your questions.  The first time this happens the ban will also expire over time, but if you continue to ask low-quality questions, the ban will be permanent until your questions improve.  It makes sense: why let you ask questions again if you've been told to improve your questions several times and didn't do it?  Note that the votes to close on some of your questions have been made by many different users, and you've run into similar problems on Space Exploration Stack Exchange.  This is not just one or two users picking on you, but a general consensus that your questions need improvement.

Low quality here doesn't just mean we don't like your questions.  It means either your questions are unclear, based on poor assumptions, or poorly suited to this site.  That means they're unlikely to solve the real issues your ideas are struggling with, or be helpful to anyone else on this site.

Here's some tips

1. Understand how this SE works.  This is a question and answer site.  You can't post the same questions here you would on a forum, or the same questions you'd sit down and ask a professor about.  In particular, the following are how to avoid particular bad practices:

   - Don't just submit an idea and ask for feedback.  Ask questions about what you don't understand about the parts of your idea.  "Would an autonomous plane work?" isn't even half as good as "Are there any current efforts to digitize ATC clearances for better automation?"
   - Don't ask a complex question with several parts.  Break down the parts and ask them individually.  It's hard to have one right answer when there are several areas to focus on.  Also, it's much better to have a question with one idea and one issue than ten ideas with ten issues.
   - Upon receiving feedback, Don't change your question significantly to the point where original answers are mostly invalid.
   - Don't ask a question about entering orbit, reentry, and rockets.  These are usually off-topic and belong in Space SE.  Being banned there isn't an excuse to ask them here.
2. Make sure your question isn't based on a false presumption.  Questions phrased like "if a blimp could carry a heavy payload into the atmosphere, could it..." are unhelpful because *a blimp can't carry a heavy payload into the atmosphere*.  Asking questions about what impossible technology would do is as useful as asking questions about what humans would do if we had wings.  Admittedly it isn't always easy to see where your presumptions are wrong, so try to go over each area where the situation in your question departs from normal practice and ask whether the departure from normal practice is feasible. The following are some near-impossible tech you've mentioned in your questions:

   - Miles-long cables
   - High altitude blimps
   - Blimps that aren't heavy and don't have lots of drag
   - Blimps that can carry heavy payloads
   - Flight not affected by turbulence
   - A space elevator that gets object into orbit by taking them up to the edge of the atmosphere but doesn't adding a ton of the required orbital speed
   - Engines that don't need oil changes
   - Somehow combining blimps, rockets, or planes in any way and ignoring the disadvantages and incompatibilities of the combination.
   - High-speed and low-complexity spinning disk vehicles
3. Don't ignore feedback and research. Few things are harder to deal with on this site than a user who bases their question on a bad presumption, then when shown the error insists that everyone else is wrong and he's right.  There's a line between "novel" and "inventive" and "impractical", and if literally everyone disagrees with you, then you've definitely crossed it.
4. Write clearly by using good writing practices. In this area some of your edits have made your questions worse, not better, by introducing bad grammar and structure. Here's some areas for improvement based on your previous posts:

   - Understand where "the","a", and "an" are needed and don't
     forget them.
   - Break up run-on sentences.
   - Begin each paragraph with the main idea for the paragraph.
   - Spell out any number under ten. One, not "1"
   - Don't capitalize words like "Solid fuel", "Electric engine" since they're not proper nouns.
   - Pay attention to the flow of ideas and sentences.  A choppy question that changes topic frequently without transitions or introductions is hard to follow.  Don't just get all your ideas out; provide some structure to them.

   I understand this may be a challenge for you, but bad writing is unclear, and unclear writing makes it harder for people to help you.
5. Don't attach images or videos that aren't on-topic, clear, and well-made.  A user is more likely to downvote your question as unhelpful if it takes a more than a few seconds to understand what your picture is of and how it relates to the most important parts of your questions.
6. Do as much research on here as possible beforehand.  We already have questions about piston engines vs aircraft engines, what speeds are considered hypersonic, which planes generate the most wake turbulence, etc.  We don't expect you to read every question on this site, but if I'm going to take half an hour to research and answer your question then you'd better have taken at least a half hour to research it.  After all, one of the reasons for downvote visible on the tooltip is "this question does not show any research effort."

Comment: Also, I noticed you had trouble with [another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56038/whould-this-balloon-fly). I'll reiterate that you shouldn't just ask "would this work" but instead tailor your questions to a specific issue, be careful about what's on-topic, and avoid attaching excessive, low-quality images.

Answer (score 7):

The [help centre](//aviation.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) has a whole page about question bans and how to get out of them. Note in particular:

> Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.

It'll be tricky to get out of the ban. Although you've posted some good questions, you have a few which are of the form, "I don't know anything about aircraft design but I have this crazy idea. Could this work?" Questions like this tend to be downvoted because they're not interesting to people who know anything about aircraft design, because there's not a real problem to be solved, and there's no specific question to answer.

I don't know how you could change those questions to make them a better fit for the site and more popular with the community. Even if you delete those posts, they'll still count against you for the question ban. If I were in your place, I'd focus on waiting for the ban to be temporarily lifted after a week, and make sure to ask a really good question then.

Comment: a week? the help page you linked speaks of 6 months.

Comment: It does, but AFAIK you get a first chance to post one question after a week, and only if that question isn't well received do you get hit with the full six months.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to have run afoul of the automatic "quality ban" system - Refer to the information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> There is something wrong with the system parameters.

No, the system is working as intended. The problem is the content of your questions. Despite the 1.5 years, it looks to me that you have not spent much time in trying to understand what makes a good question for this site and what does not.

Your last question follows straight into the path of what Cody says in [their answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3465/1467). Particularly, that question shows that you have not thought much about points 1, 2, and 5.

> My last option is to abandon this account and start a new one?

That would not get you really far. On one hand, a mod would quickly find you and suspend the new account for trying to circumvent the rules, but even before that, the system would generally block also the new account from posting questions.