# Election Time: Do new moderators change questions strictness like penalty time?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, election, moderators

I asked this question back during election before I fully understood how the SE system works. I still do not have a full comprehension because each SE seems to have different limits.

I understand that some questions I asked are low quality, but over all I most of my questions have a positive up vote. I know I have asked multiple times for it to be lifted, but each time was after I worked on the majority of my questions.
I should have not asked this question below because I now understand it is not the moderator that bans people so much it is the community and system.
Will the new moderator be more practical with penalty time on of this site or is that a setting not in their control?

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/222389) to learn how to get yourself out of this situation.

Comment: Related: [the user's previous question about the same topic](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/998)

Comment: I cannot understand why the question has been downvoted 3 times. The population is changing and up-/down-voting is less and less related to the site criteria for being on topic, accurate, or legitimate.

Comment: Now that I am a mod I looked a moment at your situation. The system says you should be able to ask new questions. Please be careful! Think carefully about what you want to ask and follow the suggestions given the previous times, if the community thinks you are still asking bad questions you might get a new block.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: if you are in doubt, ask first in chat ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar ) the other users will help you refine the question before you post it.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not something the moderators can change. The "low quality contribution ban", for lack of a better name, is set in the code of the website and cannot be accessed by users, only administrators could (but I seriously doubt they would make an exception).