# Question ban still in effect?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have an indefinite question ban. I tried to clean up my questions to no avail. Can someone check to see what else I need to do?

Comment: This is now your fifth meta question asking exactly the same thing as the precious ones. **Stop repeating yourself, you have already been answered, *multiple times!***

Comment: The instructions do not change. Follow them again. Accept that you may not be able to save your asking privilege at all, this is the cost of not making an effort in the first (second, third, ...) place to effectively learn about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 5):

You [have asked](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3443/1467) several [times](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3330/1467) in [the past](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/1467) already, and the answer does not change: you need to make the old questions liked by the community.

You managed to do this [once](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/can-the-new-moderators-allow-more-questions#comment3864_3365):

> The system says you should be able to ask new questions.

But you did not listen to [my suggestions](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/can-the-new-moderators-allow-more-questions#comment3873_3365), particularly, to ask in chat before posting

> To add to my previous comment: if you are in doubt, ask first [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) the other users will help you refine the question before you post it.

you went ahead and [posted a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44600/1467) that has not been well received, and that you have now edited about 20 times. As a consequence you have been banned again.

As said the other times, there is nothing we can do, it's up to you to improve your old questions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) or [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/)?

Your questions are a better fit there. A word of advice, *validate my ideas* kind of questions will not be well received most of the time anywhere.

---

To answer your question: breakdown your ideas down to their most basic one-problem aviation-related form. Good luck.

Comment: he's question-banned on space as well https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/941/5862

Comment: @Federico And [apparently has been asked to be un-banned multiple times there, too](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/941/2900).

Comment: @reirab you linked to the same post I linked :P

Comment: @Federico Oops, I meant to link [this one](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/934/2900).