# Appealling for question ban to be lifted

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, moderation, low-quality

I've had a couple of bad questions but overall I have a positive reputation and offended no one that I know of? How can I earn the privilege to ask again? Can I have a time when it will be lifted?

Comment: Possible dupe from your last question ban: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/59

Comment: You've asked five questions on Aviation Meta and four of them are about how to get out of question blocks. What exactly do you expect has changed about the system, that all of the existing advice and information suddenly became unusable?

Comment: @Nij Some kind of heads up would have been nice. I should be punished because I am not an expert in asking questions. It is to easy for a handful of people to close another user out of thousands.

Comment: You've had three previous heads-ups, when you got the previous question bans. You're past the point of being able to claim you didn't know what to do, unless you actively ignored the indicators. Stop asking questions and read the information you've been given already.

Answer (score 4):

Question bans are automated and none of the mods are involved.

Please read this for more details and how to get out of the ban:
[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/231188)

Comment: What if nothing works? Is there a web master?

Comment: @Muze Are you doing the things suggested in that post?

Comment: I am doing everything I can to fix my current questions without making the answers void. Still working on them as I have time..